# Conditional includes in ASP

Tags: asp-classic

We have a number of categories with products in an ASP eCommerce site and, based on the category, would like a particular file to be included. For example, if URL is:

```
viewPrd.asp?idproduct=6&idcategory=18
```

then based on `idCategory=18` I would like to include:

```
<!--#include file="menu18.asp"-->
```

If `idCategory=19` then I would like to include:

```
<!--#include file="menu19.asp"-->
```

and so on. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: [How to Implement Conditional Includes in ASP using VBScript](http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/ASPScripts/PrintPage.asp?REF=%2Fwebtech%2F022504-1.shtml)

Comment: I would consider changing your approach before trying to run includes conditionally. Ask yourself why? From experience storing individual menus in include files based on category ids isn't the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, its possible. Just leave the include statements outside the <% %> code delimiters.
This is my quick and dirty solution and it works:

```
<% session("lang") = request.querystring("lang") %>

<%if (session("lang") = "es" or session("lang") = "") then %>
<!--#include file="espanol.asp"-->
<% else %>
<!--#include file="ingles.asp"-->
<% end if %>

<!--#include file="precios.asp"-->
```

IIS will include the two files, but ASP will use only the file that satisfies the if conditions.

Answer (score 2):

I use a script taken from https://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=9796&lngWId=4 (dynamic ASP inclusion)

So after including that script in your code, you just have to write:

```
myMenu = Request.Querystring("idCategory")
Include("menu"&myMenu&".asp")
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, include files are a feature of IIS, not ASP. They are included *before* the page is sent to the ASP-processor that interprets your ASP code.
For this reason you can't have conditional includes.
The includes are already in place when the ASP code is executed.

To have conditional code in ASP you could use script components (WSC files), which you *can* include/load conditionally, or use big if...then or case.. constructions *inside* an include.

More info on the use of WSC's can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974602.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

As far i know its not possible on a "elegant way", but i suggest you to take a look in those links:

[is it possible to issue dynamic include in asp-classic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/479492/is-it-possible-to-issue-dynamic-include-in-asp-classic)

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/192144

Regards.