# Session variable for displaying page includes

Tags: asp-classic

I have a .asp page that uses sessions variables to display items specific to an administrator versus non administrator. This works everywhere throughout my site with the exception of the following:

I have a form page that is only suppose to allow SESSION("adminrole") = "admin" to update records using a form and the various fields for each part of a record.

If the SESSION("adminrole") = "nonadmin" then a different VB script is included on the page

Here is my example code at the top of an ASP page

```
<% RESPONSE.WRITE SESSION("adminrole") %>
<% IF SESSION("adminrole") = "admin" THEN %>
<!--#include file="vb/member_details.vb" -->
<% ELSEIF SESSION("adminrole") = "nonadmin" THEN%>
<!--#include file="vb/member_details_NOUPDATE.vb" -->
<% END IF %>
```

I have verified that the SESSION("adminrole") is what has been declared when a user logs in my place the Response.write so that I can visually see the session role name for the user.

The issue is that no matter who logs in, the include page that gets included is for the NON Admin role -  AND NEVER the first Include file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you have here is the order of processing in IIS.  Server-side includes get executed before the VBScript is processed.  Use a different method to include the preferred script in your page -

See the example in this link:
https://web.archive.org/web/20211020134119/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/022504-1.shtml

Example Code:

```
<%
Dim strInclude
Dim I_want_to_include_file_1
I_want_to_include_file_1 = True

If I_want_to_include_file_1 = True Then
  strInclude = getMappedFileAsString("include1.asp")
Else
  strInclude = getMappedFileAsString("include2.asp")
End If

Execute strInclude
%>
```

> Because this method does not use the built-in IIS include, the code
>   will be run when the page is run, but only one file will be included.
>   The code for the getMappedFileAsString(filepath) function is shown
>   below. Essentially it grabs the complete contents of the specified
>   filepath, returning the file's contents as a string.

```
Function getMappedFileAsString(byVal strFilename)
  Const ForReading = 1

  Dim fso
  Set fso = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FilesystemObject")

  Dim ts
  Set ts = fso.OpenTextFile(Server.MapPath(strFilename), ForReading)

  getMappedFileAsString = ts.ReadAll
  ts.close

  Set ts = nothing
  Set fso = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: It’s been [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31588880/conditional-includes-in-asp#comment51130119_31588880). Consider placing your answer there if you think it adds something.