# classic asp adding query variable

Tags: asp-classic

I'm using classic asp. I've got

```
<% If question = "where" Then %><!-- OTHER STINGING THINGS -->
<!-- #INCLUDE FILE="sting.asp" -->
<% End If %>
```

so I can get to my site with `www.mysite.com/?question=where`

I can add queries e.g.

```
<% If question = "when" Then %><!-- OTHER STINGING THINGS -->
<!-- #INCLUDE FILE="sting.asp" -->
<% End If %>
```

But I can't seem to add a different query e.g.

```
<% If answer = "now" Then %><!-- OTHER STINGING THINGS -->
<!-- #INCLUDE FILE="sting.asp" -->
<% End If %>
```

to get to `www.mysite.com/?answer=now`

What am I missing?

Comment: If you are trying to include the same file in multiple places, and only some of them work, the contents of that file would be relevant, no?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're trying to do with your code, but are you using `Request.QueryString` to assign values to your variables?

Comment: You do know you can't do conditional includes, do you?
May want to check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/479492/is-it-possible-to-issue-dynamic-include-in-asp-classic

Comment: The OP's code makes very little sense, but I don't see anything to suggest dynamic includes.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you're asking about getting the passed parameter, or the conditonal include files.

If the first then you need to get the query string first, like this:

```vb
question = Request.QueryString("question")
answer =  Request.QueryString("answer")
if question = "when" then
    ' do something
end if
if answer = "now" then
    ' do something else
end if
```

If it's about using conditional includes well, they don't work as you might expect, see this page: https://web.archive.org/web/20211020134119/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/022504-1.shtml

> The problem is caused by the order that the IIS web server processes
>   ASP page requests. The file is included before any ASP code is able to
>   run. This means that code like the following doesn't work as most
>   would expect.

```vb
<% If I_want_to_include_file_1 = True Then %>
  <!--#include file="includefile1.asp"-->
<% Else %>
  <!--#include file="includefile2.asp"-->
<% End If %>
```

> The code will run, except both files will be included no matter what.
>   The code in both files is substituted into the current page before the
>   If statement can choose which one to use. When the include files are
>   large this becomes a performance issue and can also cause problems
>   when both files define a function or variable with the same name.

They do go on to offer a solution to conditional includes, but it's not straight-forward. I think you might be better to perhaps check the value and redirect to separate pages?

```vb
If question = "when" Then
   Response.Redirect "anotherpage.asp"
end if
```